# bundle update rails resolving to 6.0.1 release candidate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to update rails from 5.2 to 6.0.  In my Gemfile I have declared:

rails (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.1.rc1

My expectation there is that I'd end up with 6.0.4 the ~> meaning optimistically resolve to the latest 6.0.* version?) Resolving to a release candidate isn't something I want to do.

I can specify it directly, of course, but I'd rather not tie the Gemfile to a specific version and count on bundler to resolve it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick fix would be to alter your Gemfile. If you want to retain the optimistic `~> 6.0` operator, you can add a second matcher for the version, like this (and thus report an error if it can't do so):

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.4'
```

I often use this pattern to lock in security patches without losing the flexibility of the `~>` operator.

I'd guess that something is preventing bundler from using a later Rails gem version - that is, you have a dependency that's locking your gem version to `6.0.1`. If the above doesn't resolve it, can you post the relevant portions of your `Gemfile` in your question? And search `Gemfile.lock` for `rails` to see whether you have any gems that require rails 6.0.1 and not later versions.